# 'new' is deprecated: -init is unavailable

Tags: objective-c, swift

```
public class Bar: NSObject {
    override init() {
             .....
    }
}
@objc public class Foo: Bar {
    @objc public override init() {
             .....
    }
}

Foo *subbrands = [Foo new]; yields a warning
```

> 'new' is deprecated: -init is unavailable

how could it possibly be unavailable?

Comment: A [mcve] would be helpful.

Comment: thanks, that was the key. example project did not have it. turned out base class of Foo did not have @objc public : its init was not exposed to objc

Comment: You should (1) edit your question to show the definition of your Foo class, and (2) post an answer to your own question explaining how you solved your problem.

Comment: done both. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

intermediate class Bar ALSO needed @objc to kill the warning

that is

```
@objc public class Bar: NSObject {
     override init() {
         .....
     }
}
```